# Add function parsing to simple pyparsing with non-numeric arguments

Tags: python, pyparsing

I am trying to add functions to expressions, with ability to accept non-numeric argument(s). Following [Add function parsing to simple pyparsing arithmetics grammar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29921504/add-function-parsing-to-simple-pyparsing-arithmetics-grammar) and https://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/fourFn.py, I could managed functions with numeric inputs. However couldn't manage to upgrade them for non-numeric inputs. Here is my test code, attempting to pass ident also along with expr to function input:

```
# fourFn.py
#
# Demonstration of the pyparsing module, implementing a simple 4-function expression parser,
# with support for scientific notation, and symbols for e and pi.
# Extended to add exponentiation and simple built-in functions.
# Extended test cases, simplified pushFirst method.
#
# Copyright 2003-2006 by Paul McGuire
#
from pyparsing import Literal,CaselessLiteral,Word,Combine,Group,Optional,\
    ZeroOrMore,Forward,nums,alphas,delimitedList
import math
import operator
import pprint 

exprStack = []

def pushFirst( strg, loc, toks ):
    exprStack.append( toks[0] )
def pushUMinus( strg, loc, toks ):
    if toks and toks[0]=='-': 
        exprStack.append( 'unary -' )
        #~ exprStack.append( '-1' )
        #~ exprStack.append( '*' )

bnf = None
def BNF():
    """
    expop   :: '^'
    multop  :: '*' | '/'
    addop   :: '+' | '-'
    integer :: ['+' | '-'] '0'..'9'+
    atom    :: PI | E | real | fn '(' expr ')' | '(' expr ')'
    factor  :: atom [ expop factor ]*
    term    :: factor [ multop factor ]*
    expr    :: term [ addop term ]*
    """
    global bnf
    if not bnf:
        point = Literal( "." )
        #e     = CaselessLiteral( "E" )
        fnumber = Combine( Word( "+-"+nums, nums ) + 
                           Optional( point + Optional( Word( nums ) ) ) 
                            )
        ident = Word(alphas, alphas+nums)

        plus  = Literal( "+" )
        minus = Literal( "-" )
        mult  = Literal( "*" )
        div   = Literal( "/" )
        lpar  = Literal( "(" ).suppress()
        rpar  = Literal( ")" ).suppress()
        addop  = plus | minus
        multop = mult | div
        expop = Literal( "^" )
        #pi    = CaselessLiteral( "PI" )
        expr = Forward()
        #function_calla = Group(ident + lpar + ident + rpar)
        function_call = Group(ident + lpar + Group(Optional(delimitedList(ident|expr))) + rpar)
        atom = (Optional("-") + ( fnumber | ident + lpar + expr + rpar |function_call).setParseAction( pushFirst ) | ( lpar + expr.suppress() + rpar )).setParseAction(pushUMinus) 
        # by defining exponentiation as "atom [ ^ factor ]..." instead of "atom [ ^ atom ]...", we get right-to-left exponents, instead of left-to-righ
        # that is, 2^3^2 = 2^(3^2), not (2^3)^2.
        factor = Forward()
        factor << atom + ZeroOrMore( ( expop + factor ).setParseAction( pushFirst ) )

        term = factor + ZeroOrMore( ( multop + factor ).setParseAction( pushFirst ) )
        expr << term + ZeroOrMore( ( addop + term ).setParseAction( pushFirst ) ) 
        bnf = expr
    return bnf
def asw(x):
    print "X is ",x
    return 1
# map operator symbols to corresponding arithmetic operations
epsilon = 1e-12
opn = { "+" : operator.add,
        "-" : operator.sub,
        "*" : operator.mul,
        "/" : operator.truediv,
        "^" : operator.pow }
fn  = { "sin" : math.sin,
        "cos" : math.cos,
        "tan" : math.tan,
        "abs" : abs,
        "trunc" : lambda a: int(a),
        "round" : round,
        "asw" : asw,
        "sgn" : lambda a: abs(a)>epsilon and cmp(a,0) or 0}
def evaluateStack( s ):
    print "s=",s
    op = s.pop()
    print "op=",op,type(op)
    if op == 'unary -':
        return -evaluateStack( s )
    #if type(op)!=str:
    #    return evaluateStack( s )

    if op in "+-*/^":
        op2 = evaluateStack( s )
        op1 = evaluateStack( s )
        return opn[op]( op1, op2 )
    elif op == "PI":
        return math.pi # 3.1415926535
    elif op == "E":
        return math.e  # 2.718281828
    elif op in fn:
        return fn[op]( evaluateStack( s ) )
    elif op[0].isalpha():
        return 0
    else:
        return float( op )
if __name__ == "__main__":      
    exprStack = []  
    res= BNF().parseString( "asw(aa)").asList()
    print "res=",res
    val = evaluateStack( exprStack[:] )
    print val
```

The result for numeric input is :

```
C:\temp>python test.py
res= ['asw', '11']
s= ['11', 'asw']
op= asw <type 'str'>
s= ['11']
op= 11 <type 'str'>
X is  11.0
1
```

Where a non-numeric input will result in:

```
C:\temp>python test.py
res= [['asw', ['aa']]]
s= [(['asw', (['aa'], {})], {})]
op= ['asw', ['aa']] <class 'pyparsing.ParseResults'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 117, in <module>
    val = evaluateStack( exprStack[:] )
  File "test.py", line 99, in evaluateStack
    if op in "+-*/^":
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not ParseResults
```

Where am I going wrong? Very new to pyparsing and still trying to figure it out.

Comment: While you're printing out the result of `parseString`, that's not what you're actually interpreting; you're interpreting the global variable `exprStack` that you push things into. So if you want to know what's different between these two cases, it's that `exprStack` you need to print out.

Comment: Also, why do you have both `ident + lpar + expr + rpar` nd `function_call` in your `atom`?

Comment: @abarnert - thanks and noted exprStack - result was showing some visual difference between both. Also as per second comment - the code is not very clean - leftovers are there from trial and error + considering my lack of experience with pyparsing. However I don't think that is causing the original issue I am trying to understand.

Comment: Pyparsing is no longer hosted on wikispaces.com. Go to https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your culprit is in your adding of `function_call` into `atom` at the end, and in making `function_call` a Group.

```
function_call = (ident + lpar + Group(Optional(delimitedList(expr))) + rpar)
atom = (Optional("-") + ( fnumber | function_call | ident).setParseAction( pushFirst ) | ( lpar + expr.suppress() + rpar )).setParseAction(pushUMinus)
```

Remember that '|' generates `MatchFirst` expressions, which will match on the first given expression that matches. If you define `atom` to match on `ident` first, then you will never match a `function_call`, since your function starts with an identifier. You must first check if the identifier you are parsing is the start of a function call before determining that it is actually a lone identifier.

Also, `function_call` must not be a Group. The way this parser works is to parse and push all the arguments onto the stack, and then finally push the function name onto the stack. But this only works if `function_call` is not a Group - otherwise you are pushing the entire parsed function ParseResults onto the stack.

Finally, note that I reduced `function_call`'s arguments to just be `expr`s, not `ident | expr`. A lone `ident` *is* an `expr`, so the alternation is not necessary - and in fact it is messing things up again, for the same reason that listing `ident` ahead of `function_call` in `atom` is a problem.

Comment: Thanks - that solved it, and the explanation is great.